# How do I solve this statistics question on approximation of distribution?

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference, probability-limit-theorems

Suppose that $U_i\sim \operatorname{iid} \operatorname{Unif} [-1,1]$ and consider $$\ X = \frac{U_1 + U_2 + \cdots + U_n} {\sqrt{U_1^2 + U_2^2 + \cdots + U_n^2}}$$
for large $n.$ What is the probability that $X > 1.$ Justify any approximation you use. How large $n$ should be?

Comment: I think $X$ is also uniform from simulation.

Comment: Divide both numerator and denominator by $\sqrt{n}$ and use CLT for numerator, LLN for denominator and Slutsky's theorem for fraction.

Comment: Could you please show me some steps on the application of LLN on the denominator. That'd be very kind of you.

Answer (score 2):

Note that $EU = 0$ and $Var(U) = EU^2 = 1/3$, then according to the comment by Nch,
$$
X = \frac{\sqrt{3}\sum_{i=1}^n U_i/\sqrt{n}}{\sqrt{3}\sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^n U_i^2 / n}}.
$$ 
Now, using WLLN and the continuous mapping theorem 
$$
\sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^n U_i^2 / n} \xrightarrow{p}\sqrt{E U_i^2}=1/\sqrt{3}, \,\, n \to \infty , 
$$
according to CLT 
$$
\sqrt{3}\sum_{i=1}^n U_i/\sqrt{n} \xrightarrow{D}Z, 
$$
where $Z \sim N(0,1)$, thus using Slutsky's theorem we have
$$
X \xrightarrow{D} \frac{Z}{\sqrt{3}/\sqrt{3}} = Z.
$$
Hence, for large enough $n$
$$
P(X>1) \approx P(\sqrt{3}Z>1)=1-\Phi(1/\sqrt{3}).
$$

Comment: You sure about about $X \xrightarrow{D} \sqrt{3}Z$?

Comment: Nope. Corrected. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

More of a comment ...  The $n=2$ case yields the symmetric Boobies distribution with pdf:

[image]

The exact cdf for the $n=2$ case is given below.

The following diagram illustrates convergence as $n$ increases...

[image]

Comparison to a standard Normal pdf when $n=7$:

[image]

and when $n = 20$:

[image]

**Addendum:** Given the joint pdf of $(U_1,U_2)$ as say $f(u_1,u_2)$, the cdf $P(X<x)$ is:

[image]